# Simple React.js implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a relatively simple app with a header and a main section of content.  The main section can show up to 4 different types of components, but only 1 component at a time.  Each component needs to have the ability to transition (slide) from one component to the next depending on the state.

As of now, my main application component holds the state as to which component should be shown.  This main application component also renders all 4 of the top-level components.  Each of the 4 top-level components `hide/show` themselves based upon the application state.  Is this the **best** way of toggling the different components on and off, or should I manually mount and unmount each component?  If I take the `mount/unmount` approach am I still able to easily transition each element?

Answer (score 2):

I would have upvoted or commented on Douglas' answer but I dont have enough rep!

ReactCSSTransitionGroup will do what you want. Adopt the [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) example to suit your purposes and dont forget to write your animation styles first (ReactCSSTransitionGroup relys on CSS animationend callback to know when the elements have left/entered the dom). It will add helper classes for you so you can create a transition effect between the (incoming and outgoing) elements.

Comment: I would probably upvote your answer if you'd have added some example so your answer would be even more informative / descriptive than the one posted earlier.

Comment: I did link to the tutorial however the only time i have implimented this in real-life practical use is on a internal app (which i obviously cant share). Here is a link to a test page i made when studying react. The menu fade in-out effect uses ReactCSSTransitionGroup to do a simple opacity transition effect when the list items are added to the DOM:
http://framework.anthonycregan.co.uk/
I hope that is of some use.

(now about that upvote...)

Answer (score 0):

A [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) will probably do what you need, at the very least you could look at the implementation to see how they do it.